# Binding to collection in viewmodel with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem

Tags: wpf, grid, master-detail, selecteditem

I have a grid displaying the contents of an observableCollection of Persons, and two textboxes showing the properties of the selected row. A master-detail view if you will.

When assigning the observablecollection to the datacontext you can simply do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <igWPF:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="0" DataSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Height="21" Width="100" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="21" Width="100" Text="{Binding Age}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

 </Grid>
```

The IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem-property makes sure the selected item in the grid is the one that is treated in the textboxes.

I was wondering if it is possible to do this exact thing when the observablecollection is not in the datacontext directly, but rather is located in a viewmodel (which is assigned to the datacontext of the window).

```
public class TestViewModel: DependencyObject
{
    public TestViewModel(){
        Results = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        Results.Add(new Person { Age = "23", Name = "Able" });
        Results.Add(new Person { Age = "25", Name = "Baker" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TagDlgmtEntity> Results
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Person>)GetValue(ResultsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResultsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Results", typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>), typeof(TestViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

I would like not to reassign a datacontext on a lower level in the visual tree, or bind with the selectedItem property of the grid.

Is it possible to use this mechanism this way?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend implementing the ViewModel differently. Either implement your own ViewModelBase, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` or (better IMO) use an MVVM framework like e.g. [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), which gives you a decent ViewModelBase for free. You normally don't have to fiddle around with dependency properties in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Declare your binding like this:
`DataSource="{Binding Results}"`

---

**Example ViewModel**

Assumption: `ViewModelBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (see my comment  on the question)

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly List<Person> _results;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _results = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Age = "23", Name = "Able"},
            new Person {Age = "25", Name = "Baker"}
        };

        ResultsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_results);

        ResultsView.CurrentChanged += (sender, args) => RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
    }

    public ICollectionView ResultsView { get; private set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Person) ResultsView.CurrentItem).Name;
        }
    }
}
```